# Stripe: How to set up recurring payments without plan?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, forms, stripe-payments

First time working with Stripe API. Implementing it on WordPress using PHP and JS.
Working on a donation form. Donor should be able to choose a suggested amount (radio buttons-25,50,75,100) or pay as he/she wishes (text field after selecting 'other'). I was able to get this working.

There is a check box to set the amount up as a recurring payment. I created recurring payment plans for the fixed options like 25, 50, 100 etc.

How do I set up a recurring payment if the donor chooses a custom amount? Can't find the relevant API. Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you'll need to [create a new customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#create_customer).

On submit, you could use the custom amount to [create a new plan](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#create_plan):

```
$current_time = time();
$plan_name = strval( $current_time );

Stripe_Plan::create(array(
        "amount" => $_POST['custom-amount'],
        "interval" => "month",
        "name" => "Some Plan Name " . $_POST['customer-name'],
        "currency" => "usd",
        "id" => $plan_name
    )
);
```

Keep in mind that the `'id'` needs to be unique. You could use the customer's name, a time stamp, or some other random method to ensure that this is always the case.

You'd then just [create the subscription on the newly-added customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#create_subscription):

```
$customer = Stripe_Customer::retrieve($customer_just_created);
$customer->subscriptions->create(array("plan" => $plan_name));
```

You probably will be able to omit the first line above, as you should already have a customer variable assigned from when the customer was actually created.

Comment: You mentioned that the id should be unique.. why don't you reflect that in your code? Just add the customer name as you did to the plan name

Comment: There's no guarantee the customer name will be unique...But sure, I'll add something.

Comment: That is true. `time()` is probably the best approach short of querying a database. I don't use stripe so I don't know but is the id what you pass into `subscriptions->create()`? If so, you need to store the variable and use it there too.

Comment: Edited for that as you were typing the comment. ;-)

Comment: You got the +1 ;) Shame the OP seems to have deserted.. Hopefully this answer will help others!

Comment: Sorry for replying so late guys. I tried the above code and it works perfectly!

Comment: I don't like this solution because it ends up junking up the plans in the dashboard. If I later have two or three fixed-price subscription plans for something else, there are now potentially dozens or even hundreds of plans junking stuff up. To me this is at best a hack, not really a solution.

Answer (score 22):

Another approach that Stripe suggests is to setup a plan with a recurring amount of $1 (or $0.01 for more flexibility) and then vary the quantity as needed.

e.g. Using the $0.01 plan approach, if I wanted to charge 12.50/month I could adjust the quantity like so:

```
$customer->subscriptions->create(array("plan" => "basic", "quantity" => "1250"));
```

Stripe Support

- [How can I create plans that don't have a fixed price?](https://support.stripe.com/questions/how-can-i-create-plans-that-dont-have-a-fixed-price)
- [Subscription Quantities](https://stripe.com/blog/new-recurring-billing-features)

Comment: Oh wow. This is a crazy idea. Would never think of it. So this ensures that I don't need to make custom plans for each misc amount. Interesting!

Comment: So nasty workaround but thanks for sharing this! The 'plan' parameter for subscriptions should be optional.

Answer (score 3):

This is low tech, but the easiest thing I found was to use as little of the Stripe API as possible. Instead of creating subscription plans and products and things like that, you just:

- Create a stripe customer.
- Charge them with a cron job.

If you already know how to charge somebody, you just have to figure out how to create the customer, and then the rest is good to go.

This means you shift some of Stripe's cleverness to our own infrastructure, but I actually found this easier to think about/maintain than thinking through all of Stripe's API docs and features.

Comment: I feel the same with you, Stripe's recurring automation makes it complex for business that require custom charges or custom subscription periods